# On passing arguments to super class, an error flags: "module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class info:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._variables = kwargs


class waybill(info):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(waybill, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

**Error -:** `module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)`

What could probably the reason why this error is flagging? I am using `Python 3.2`

Comment: I guess my old comment still applies, does it literally say `module.__init__()...` or did you rename it?  I still don't see any potential for it being interpreted as a 3 argument call.  Are you sure that error occurs in this code?

Comment: with quote, yes it does literally say that.

Comment: I am new to Python, whats the new style then?

Comment: @ Jeff Mercado: Side question are you a fil? Its the class "waybill(info):" line, I am using PyDev in Eclypse

Comment: @LemuelAdane let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1530/discussion-between-jeff-mercado-and-lemuel-adane)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is info defined in the same file? Or is it info.info from info.py? If you're importing info, trying changing it to the following:

```
from info import info
```

Additional information: If you simply `import info` then `info` is a module, and `waybill` is subclassing `module`.

Comment: You're right, it turns out he had it in different files.

Comment: Thanks, strange error message though.

Answer (score 3):

```
super(waybill, self).__init__(kwargs)
```

should be:

```
super(waybill, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```